# Spring Web MVC HttpRequest not functioning correctly

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am unable to get my controller to respond to my HTTP request in my Spring Web MVC application.  The project will deploy but will only load the default 'index.jsp' file. I believe my problem may be within the context.xml file but am unsure how to properly configure the file if it is the issue.

Project Structure:

-src/main/java/controllers/projectGitControllers

-src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/projectGit-servletConfig.xml

-src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/homepage.jsp

URL I am trying to use

-`http://localhost:8080/projectGit/getHomepage`

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>projectGit</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>projectGit</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/projectGit-servletConfig.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>projectGit</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**homepage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>projectGit Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${titleHomepage}</h1>
    <p>Working</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**projectGitControllers.java**

```
package controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class projectGitControllers {

    @RequestMapping(value="/getHomepage")
    public String getHomepage(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("titleHomepage", "ProjectHub");

        return "homepage";
    }

}
```

**projectGit-servletConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.application.projectGit.controllers"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp" />


</beans>
```

Comment: if you are spring beginner, I strongly recommend you to use modern xml free configuration. Example: http://www.techzoo.org/spring-framework/step-by-step-xml-free-spring-mvc-3-configuration.html

Comment: I have done that in the past and wanted to expand my knowledge.

Comment: what is the result if you browse to : http://localhost:8080/getHomepage

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Controller` class has `package controllers;`

and you have

`base-package="com.application.projectGit.controllers"`

Therefore your `@Controller` never is created how a bean.

Therefore change from `package controllers;` to `package com.application.projectGit.controllers;`

**Note:** is a bad practice use uppercase characters for a package name

**Addition 01:**

From:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"  
      class="org.s....InternalResourceViewResolver" 
      p:prefix="WEB-INF/pages/" 
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

update `p:prefix="WEB-INF/pages/"` to `p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"`. Therefore now is `/WEB-INF`, it starts with `/`

If you get the same or new error messages, consider in update your post about to include the complete error stack trace.

Comment: this did not fix my issue either :(.

Comment: See `Addition 01`. Consider in add (not update) your new changes in your post, it to keep the track.

Answer (score 0):

Your viewResolver is pointed to `WEB-INF/jsp/`

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Whereas your jsp is located under `WEB-INF/pages`

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/homepage.jsp
```

Comment: Hi Jerin and thanks for your response, I made the correct changes and still am presented with the same problem.